# what is the correct syntax for MySQL alter table query?

Tags: php, mysql

While I try to run the following mysqli call

```
$strSQL3=mysqli_query($connection," alter table mark_list add column 'mark' int(2) " ) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

returns error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `mark int(2)` at line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes (`'`) denote string literals. Object names (such as columns), are not strings - juts lose the quotes:

```
$strSQL3 = mysqli_query($connection ,"alter table mark_list add column mark int(2)" ) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing *'mark'* to *mark* like this:

```
    $strSQL3=mysqli_query($connection,
             " alter table mark_list add column mark int(2) " ) 
              or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you need to remove the quotes near `'`mark

```
$strSQL3=mysqli_query($connection," alter table mark_list add column mark int(2) " ) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```